# How to select all records from one table when there's not a match on a join table?

Tags: mysql

I'm making a simple notification system, but I can't get my query to work, I'm getting confused.

I want to select all the notifications from table 1 that are "unseen", considering unseen when there's not a matching result from table 2.

```
table1 t1 (notifications)
+---+-------+--------+
+id + title + content+
+---+-------+--------+
+ 1 + some..+lorem...+
+ 2 + sosf  + sfdsdf +
+ 3 +  asdf + dsfd   +
+---+-------+--------+


table2 t2 (seen notification by each user)
+-------+---------------+
+id_user+id_notification+
+-------+---------------+
+   1   +  1            +
+   1   +  3            +
+-------+---------------+
```

So I want to query all the record from t1 when there's not a matching record on t2.

I tried

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.id_user IS NULL AND t1.id IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.id DESC;
```

With no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` to JOIN the tables on `notification_id`. Where there is no matching value in `t2`, the value of `t2.notification_id` will be `NULL`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.id_notification = t1.id
WHERE t2.id_notification IS NULL
```

Output:

```
id  title   content
2   sosf    sfdsdf
```

To see whether a particular user had seen notifications, change the `ON` condition to something like:

```
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.id_notification = t1.id AND t2.id_user = 2
```

This would give you all the notifications that had not been seen by user 2, in this case all of them:

```
id  title   content
1   some..  lorem...
2   sosf    sfdsdf
3   asdf    dsfd
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9203/8)

Comment: Thanks Nick, but in this case you will be getting all notifications no matter wich user is, what about if I'm the user with the ID 1 and we need to find a match of both IDs (user and notification) in order to call it "seen" or if there isn't "unseen".

Comment: Hi Bobby, in that case you would change the `ON` condition to include the user id. See my edit.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, i can't give upvotes so far, but i did marked it as solved. Thanks!